# How to make extension/plugin for fl studio?

Tags: plugins, automation, workflow, ui-automation

I am using Fl studio to make 3d audio(audio alternates between audio channels).But I have to do many of the same processes by hand every time.So, I want to create a plugin that does the repetitive stuff for me.

How do I create plugins for FL studio? I know C++ and python(If that helps).What is the process of making a plugin for Fl studio(not just for this 3d audio problem)?

Comment: Access to https://www.image-line.com/developers/index.php [Download the sdk](https://forum.image-line.com/viewtopic.php?f=700&t=12092&_ga=2.228261341.1751206339.1571208639-949054394.1571208639) You also have a specific forum for posting your questions [here](https://forum.image-line.com/viewforum.php?f=700&_ga=2.228261341.1751206339.1571208639-949054394.1571208639)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.image-line.com/developers/
The FL Studio SDK provides you the API libraries and developer tools necessary to build, test, and debug plugins for FL Studio.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).